# Ternary operator inside if condition not transpiled properly using babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs, conditional-operator

```
let a = null, b = null;

if ((a !== null) && a.active && ((a === null) ? (a === b) : true)) {

}
```

After babel transpile above condition is transformed into

```
if (a !== null && a.active && a === null ? a === b : true) {

}
```

and it is always returning true because ternary operator has less precedency than comparison operators
any solution not to omit parentheses in this kind of conditions?

Comment: Whether you set both `a` and `b` to either `null` or `undefined` the `===` would always be true.. Which is why babel is removing your declaration line..

Comment: What settings are you using? It preserves the outer parenthesis if I try it [on the Babel website](https://babeljs.io/repl#?code_lz=DYUwLgBAhhC8EDsCuxgBoICM6JcA3AFCECWAZhABSUwCEs8yqAlBAGRvQB0UAxmCQBuIdp2owGjPKwD8VCQyysAXBDAAnJCGasA3sQC-QA).

Comment: @AdityaParab - the code definitely behaves differently

Comment: This looks like a bug. Are you using the latest version of babel?

Comment: Notice you can simplify the whole thing to just `if (a !== null && a.active)` - no point in checking `a === b` if `a === null` since this only runs when `a !== null`